# Unable to attach server portion of an extension to the debugger

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, language-server-protocol

I'm following the guide on building a language server extension (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/example-language-server) and it says to debug the server portion, you simply F5 from the editor with the server code within it. However, whenever I do this I get:

Error cannot connect to runtime process (timeout after 5000ms).

Answer (score 0):

And, of course, it was a FAQ at the bottom of the page itself:

You will see this timeout error if the server isn't running when you try to attach the debugger. The client starts the language server so make sure you have started the client in order to have a running server.